# Computing contraction of a 3-form with vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am trying to understand the idea of contraction by computing the contraction of

$$dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$$

over the vector field

$$x\frac{\partial }{\partial y}-z\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$$

I got that this is equal to

$$dx(-z\frac{\partial }{\partial x})\wedge dy \wedge dz+dx\wedge dy(x\frac{\partial }{\partial y})\wedge dz$$
$$=-zdy\wedge dz+xdx\wedge dz$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You mean $x\,dx\wedge dz$, but be careful about signs.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, that was a typo. Though could you please shed some light on which signs are wrong? I looked through it and don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: You have to feed the vector into the first $1$-form, so switches are required. The second term requires one switch, hence a negative.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see, so it should be $-zdy\wedge dz-xdx\wedge dz$, right?

Comment: Yuppers. ${{}}$ :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you!